# List/Install PHP Web Stack Components

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl, webmatrix

I've installed WordPress 3.0.2 on my local box using MS Webmatrix (beta 3).  Webmatrix tells me the site uses PHP 5.2. Now I need to install a WordPress plugin (JanRain Engage, to be precise) that requires cURL-SSL and JSON.

Before installing the plugin, how do I determine if I already have cURL-SSL and JSON?  How should I go about installing them if I don't have them?  Are there special instructions within a Webmatrix context?

**update**
What is the easiest way to run any of the suggested php code or snippets, such as phpinfo(), assuming a Webmatrix environment?  I verified that I could execute a php snippet, "using" Webmatrix, by making an html file and viewing it from my web browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /><title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It worked.  But is that really the easiest way to execute a PHP function?  Seems a little indirect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First port of call: `phpinfo()`. It will tell you about curl and *should* tell you about SSL (I have no experience with that so I don't know what the entry looks like, but it should be in the curl section).

json_decode and _encode() are part of the core since 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

you dont install json, it's just a way for javascript to create associative objects if you were referring to the encoding/decoding functions their available since 5.2.0 but you could make your own quite easily.

you can find a class [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3512-PHP-Encode-and-decode-PHP-values-in-JSON-format.html)

To see if curl is istalled just do `var_dump(curl_version());` if you get an error to activate it open up php.ini find the line with `;extension=php_curl.dll`  and remove `;`

Answer (score 0):

To check lively, you can use `function_exists`:

```
if ( !function_exists('curl_init') ) { // don't use cURL module
```